# ViewBag throws NullReferenceException (Object Not Sent to Instance)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ViewBag Data throws this exception and Im not sure why? The exception errors in the View Class on the line containing ViewBag.Data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Response Text</th>
    <th>Date & Time of Update</th>
    <th>Username</th>
</tr>

@foreach (OfficiumWebApp.Models.ResponseViewModel item in ViewBag.Data)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ResponseText</td>
        <td>
        <td>@item.DateTimeOfUpdate</td>
        <td>
        <td>@item.Username</td>
        <td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here is the method in my controller:

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var yyy = (from a in db.Responses select new ResponseViewModel {ResponseText = a.ResponseText, DateTimeOfUpdate = a.DateTimeOfUpdate.ToString(), Username = a.UserName});
        ViewBag.Data = yyy;
        var LogResponses = from b in db.Responses where b.LogID == LogID select b;
        return View(LogResponses.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `null` value check for `ViewBag.Data` in your view like below:

```
@if (ViewBag.Data != null)
{
   foreach (OfficiumWebApp.Models.ResponseViewModel item in ViewBag.Data)
   {
     <tr>
        <td>@item.ResponseText</td>
        <td>
        <td>@item.DateTimeOfUpdate</td>
        <td>
        <td>@item.Username</td>
        <td>
     </tr>
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It doesnt throw any exception now but it still doesn't work. It only outputs the words in the table (response text, date time of update, username) and not actually any of the result data.

Comment: That's because the result of your query `yyy` is null, unlike `ViewData`, `ViewBag` doesn't have a null value check by default.

Comment: I need to add where a.LogID == LogID into my yyy query. How do I add the where clause

Comment: like: `from a in db.Responses where a.LogID == logID select.. `